# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService though exported from another module

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I am using `@nestjs/jwt` in my NestJS project.

I have two modules, `AuthModule` and `AppModule`.

- The `AuthModule` uses the `@nestjs/jwt`
- The `AppModule` invoke auth service from `AuthModule`.

`AuthService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ForbiddenException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly jwt: JwtService) {}

  async validate(token: string) {
    return this.jwt.verify(token);
  }
   ...
}
```

AuthModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TokenService } from './auth.service'
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
          secret: "mysecret",
          signOptions: { expiresIn: "60s" },
        }),
  ],
  // I provide AuthService & JwtService
  providers: [AuthService, JwtService], 
  // I export AuthService and JwtService
  exports: [AuthService, JwtService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  // I provide AuthService & JwtService also in AppModule
  providers: [AppService, JwtService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(The `AppController` invokes `AuthService` instance to validate token.)

I constantly get error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0]
```

Why is that? Where do I miss?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add `JwtService` to the `providers`. Nest will look through the current module's `providers`, then the imported module's `exports`, and then the global module's `exports` to find providers that are not immediately in the level it's resolving the providers in. This means that for `AuthService` it'll look up to the `JwtModule`'s `exports` and find the `JwtService` already created, and use that instance. Then in the `AppModule` you don't need to mention the `AuthService` or `JwtService`, just import the `AuthModule` that exports the `AuthService` and `JwtModule` (doing some [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting)) and you should be good to go

---

EDIT: Added module code:

#### AuthModule

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TokenService } from './auth.service'
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
          secret: "mysecret",
          signOptions: { expiresIn: "60s" },
        }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

#### AppModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was actually my 1st version code, however since I keep getting that error, I then explictly provide `AuthService` and `JwtService` in both `AuthModule` and `AppModule`.   I tried again removing the two services in provider array of `AppModule` only import the `AuthModule`, the error is the same.

Comment: What was the error with the first version, because it probably was not the same, but similar. The current error is because you have `JwtService` in a `providers` array.

Comment: Exactly the same error I meant. Like I said I tried again reverting back to 1st version, it is indeed exactly the same error.

Comment: Do you still have `JwtService` in a `providers` array then?

Comment: I have the `JwtService` in the `providers` of `AuthModule` not `AppModule`

Comment: First line of my answer. **You don't need to add `JwtService` to the `providers`.** That goes for **all** `providers` arrays, because the `JwtModule` already creates the `JwtService` and `exports` it.

Comment: I actually tried that removing `JwtService` from providers of both module.  same error.

Comment: I think it is easier if you just provide the code of the modules which you feel should work. I have tried all things I can come up with including what we discussed, but it is always same error.

Comment: I've edited your modules and added them as code snippets. With what information you've provided in the post, this should all be correct

Comment: ```Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?)```, same. But thanks.

Comment: Then you have `JwtService` somewhere else in a `providers` or you haven't recompiled your code. Based on what you've provided in your question, there's no more help I can provide. If you want to drop a link to your git repo, I can take a look

Comment: No, I don't have `JwtService` elsewhere. But thank you, I am not able to provide the repo since it is company codebase.  I will figure out why.